# Log4J: remove properties from CloseableThreadContext

Tags: java, apache, log4j

From what I can see, `CloseableThreadContext` only exposes methods for adding properties, not removing them. Would setting a property to null (e.g. `contextInstance.put("myprop",null)`) achieve this? Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; the only way to remove properties is to close the `CloseableThreadContext` - which removes them all.